# How to Count Entries on Same Day and Sum Amount based on the Count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to produce Table2 below - which essentially counts the rows that have the same day and adds up the "amount" column for the rows that are on the same day.

[image]

I found a solution online that can count entries from the same day, which works:

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime) AS date, 
    COUNT(datetime) AS date1
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime);
```

[image]

It is partially what I am looking for, but I am having difficulty trying to display all the column names.

In my attempt, I have all the columns I want but the Accumulated Count is not accurate since it counts the rows with unique IDs (because I put "id" in GROUP BY):

```
SELECT *, count(id) OVER(ORDER BY DateTime) as accumulated_count, 
SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY DateTime) AS Accumulated_Amount 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY date(datetime), id
```

[image]

I've been working on this for days and seemingly have come across every possible outcome that is not what I am looking for. Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cumulative sum and count should be calculated for each day

```
with Table1 (id,datetime,client,product,amount) as(values 
  (1 ,to_timestamp('2020-07-08 07:30:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Tom','Bill Payment',24),
  (2 ,to_timestamp('2020-07-08 07:50:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Tom','Bill Payment',27),
  (3 ,to_timestamp('2020-07-09 08:20:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Tom','Bill Payment',37)
)
SELECT
  Table1.*, 
  count(*) over (partition by DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime) 
                order by datetime asc ) accumulated_count,
  sum(amount) over (partition by DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime) order by datetime asc) accumulated_sum
FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to familiar with postgresql but this does what you ask fror.

```
with data (id,date_time,client,product,amount) as(
select 1 ,to_timestamp('Jul 08 2020, 07:30:10','Mon DD YYYY, HH24:MI:SS'),'Tom','Bill',24 Union all
select 2 ,to_timestamp('Jul 08 2020, 07:50:30','Mon DD YYYY, HH24:MI:SS'),'Tom','Bill',27 Union all
select 3 ,to_timestamp('Jul 09 2020, 08:20:10','Mon DD YYYY, HH24:MI:SS'),'Tom','Bill',37 
)
select d.id,d.date_time,d.client,d.product,d.amount,
(select count(*) from data d1 
where d1.date_time <= d.date_time and date(d1.date_time) = date(d.date_time)  ) acc_count,
(select sum(amount) from data d1 
where d1.date_time <= d.date_time and date(d1.date_time) = date(d.date_time)  ) acc_amount
from data d
```

[image]